# deadlock error when try to update from gridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, updates, deadlock

> Transaction (Process ID 588) was deadlocked on lock resources with
>   another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the
>   transaction.

i get that error when i try to update data from datagridview how can i solve it or what is the problem with my update code and thank you ,

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("***"))
        {
            con.Open();


            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                // INSERT command:
                using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tabl2 SET TEL8=@TEL8 WHERE id=@id and CIVILIDD=@CIVILIDD ", con))
                {
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CIVILIDD", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEL8", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());

                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully UPDATE....");
        }
    }
```

sql server table :

```
id = int
CIVILIDD = bigint
TEL8 = nvarchar (MAX)
```

Comment: did it execute at least one?

Comment: Why did you think this code is the one which is causing the deadlock?

Comment: @GabLlorico some of records updated

Comment: @dedecos because the data in the datagridview and i just click the button to update the records with that code

Comment: @AhmedAlkhteeb so this function is **the only** code that is executed from the click of the button and the deadlock happening?

Comment: @dedecos yes sir

Comment: im confused, `//Insert command` but there is an update?

Comment: @GabLlorico it is an update command i will correct the # sorry

Comment: @AhmedAlkhteeb if you comment all the code inside `Button2_Click` the deadlock does not happen?

Comment: maybe dataGridView1.Rows is refreshed automatically each time you add a db row?

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori the datagridview is an excel sheet read the sheet one time only and didn't changed

Comment: is db in single user mode?

Comment: added an answer

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori NO but i try it when i'm the only one who use it and have the same error

Comment: @GabLlorico what do you mean with that (the update code is in the button2 only )

Comment: The one you have as the sample code, replace it with your update code. The alter database string is an sql query. I just put the idea of execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this if this will work

```
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tabl2 SET TEL8=@TEL8 WHERE id=@id and CIVILIDD=@CIVILIDD ", con))
{
    com.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
    com.Parameters.Add("@CIVILIDD", SqlDbType.BigInt);
    com.Parameters.Add("@TEL8", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        com.Parameters["@id"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
        com.Parameters["@CIVILIDD"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
        com.Parameters["@TEL8"].Value =  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
    }
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

or

alter your db to `single_user` before running the `update` then reverting it back to `multi_user`

```
new SqlCommand("Alter Database {databaseName} SET SINGLE_USER With ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", con);
//your update commands
new SqlCommand("Alter Database {databaseName} SET MULTI_USER With ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", con);
```

also for this to occur,

- check all sql connection and command creation, if all of them are using `using SqlCommand` and `using SqlConnection`. I believe this might be the reason for it to fail as a connection and command are not yet dispose.
- *maybe* a very busy server, research on `commandtimeout` and `connectiontimeout`, `commandtimeout` setting will cause your query to wait up until the query is executed if set to 0. `connectiontimeout` will cause your connection attempt to wait up until it has made a connection if set to 0.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198345/discussion-on-answer-by-gab-llorico-deadlock-error-when-try-to-update-from-gridv).

Comment: I see. mod-created rooms grant access to all though https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/198345/?tab=access